# Fix shipping method name in Magento

Tags: magento

I have this weird issue. One of the shipping method name `Overnight` is being shown as just `O`, both on frontend while checking out and it backend while placing an order or under shipping methods.

I don't see any option to rename it or anything. I was told on IRC that under Table Rates tab (System > Config > Shipping Methods), I can set the Method Name and Title but its already set as something else.

Is it possible that something else is overriding it? Where it is stored in the database?

**Updated progress:**

I ran the following query `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'carriers/%/title';` but there is no method named `Overnight` or `O`, I think something is overriding its name on the fly. Any pointers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There might be a translation file changing the value.

Check:

```
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/locale/[region]/translate.csv
```

Comment: Don't have that line in my translate.csv file under my package. And base folder, doesn't have a locale folder. So where should I look for next? Is it possible that some module can change the translation? My guess is that file was accidently changed before saving.

Answer (score 0):

On the template (*app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml* for me), the title is displayed like this, and I assume that the same method is used on the back-end :

```
<label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() ?>
```

This method get the title saved on the core_config_data table. Connect to MySQL and use this request :

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'carriers/%/title';
```

You will see the title displayed for each shipping method. Maybe the title saved is **O** and not **Overnight**

Comment: Thanks! But its not there. I updated the question with a screenshot of query result. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: You must have installed or created a module to add this shipping method. Maybe the issue is how the module save the shipment method data.

Is there in this module on `system.xml` file in the etc/ folder, or a `<config>` section in the config.xml ?

You can also try to log the content of the $_rate variable in the template file mentioned above. It can give a clue of how the title is stored.